# Can't install module python pip

Tags: python, pip, snmp

i'm new to python. I'd like to use pysnmp module, so i tried to install it with pip but i'm getting errors from it :

```
Failed building wheel for pycrypto
```

I tried on multiple system (Ubuntu, Debian and RH) and I always get the same error. How can i install pysnmp ? Or are there any other alternative to work with snmp with python ?

Shell Command :

```
sudo -H pip install pysnmp
```

Result :

```
...
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating src/config.h
    warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastm                                                                                                 ath.
    building 'Crypto.Hash._MD2' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fstack-prot                                                                                                 ector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOUR                                                                                                 CE=2 -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c                                                                                                  src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/MD2.o
    src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-                                                                                                 build-7gwchpkq/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(_                                                                                                 _file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp                                                                                                 /pip-6mlabkyq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --co                                                                                                 mpile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7gwchpkq/pycrypto/
```

Comment: tried both `sudo pip install pysnmp` and `sudo -H pip install pysnmp` and it worked. I also uninstalled `pycrypto` and installed it new, worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `src/MD2.c:31:20`: fatal error: `Python.h`: No such file or directory

The actual error is that you do not have the dev files for python language (`python.h` not found).

So, install `python-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install  python-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py

python ez_setup.py

easy_install pysnmp
```

Comment: I get this : 
Running pycrypto-2.6.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-g0ahfypn/pycrypto-2.6.1/egg-dist-tmp-20rtwgcx
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

Comment: I get "Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/setuptools-20.3.1-py3.4.egg"

Comment: I found this on another thread: `apt-cache search python3-dev`
`sudo apt-get install python3-dev`
`pip install pycrypto`